# Ein schönes Wort für "Vorfertigkeiten" gesucht

Tags: single-word-request

Im Rahmen einer Universitätsveranstaltung möchten wir ermitteln, was die Studenten vorher schon können. Der kanonische Name "Vorkenntnistest" trifft es nicht wirklich, da wir (ganz artig gemäß Bologna) natürlich auch *Fähigkeiten* abprüfen.

Den Teil *-kenntnis-* einfach durch *-fertigkeiten-* oder *-fähigkeiten-* zu ersetzen, ergibt kein wirklich griffiges Wort. Gibt es da etwas Schönes?

Um die Anforderungen klar zu machen, ich suche ein kerniges Wort (oder eine Phrase) für

- einen Test, der
- Wissen und Fähigkeiten abprüft, die
- bereits vorliegen (also den status quo).

Es wird sich um einen mathematischen Kontext handeln, wenn das relevant ist.

Comment: nur so: wozu brauchen wir das Präfix *Vor...*? Kentnisse und Fertigkeiten existieren doch auch ohne... ;)

Comment: @Takkat Stimmt. Es macht aber die Bedeutung des Tests klar: "Was können Sie *vor* unserer Veranstaltung schon?". Die Begriffe "erforderliche Vorkenntnisse" und "Vorveranstaltung" sind üblich und tauchen auch in Ordnungen auf. Das heißt nicht, dass das Präfix im zu findenden schönen Wort enthalten sein muss, erklärt aber vielleicht die Genesis unseres Gedankengangs.

Comment: Erfüllt Deine Kriterien nur mit Einschränkungen, aber der Vollständigkeit halber: *Bestandsaufnahme.*

Comment: Da gibt's doch das schöne deutsche Wort "Baselining" ;)

Comment: Die Antwort 'Grundlagentest' gefällt mir ebenso wie Takkats Hinweis. Ergänzen möchte ich noch, dass das Anwenden mathematischer Kenntnisse schlecht von diesen zu trennen ist. Zu wissen, wie man die 2. Ableitung einer Funktion bildet bedeutet auch in der Lage zu sein, es zu tun. Daher würde (Vor-)Kenntnisse m.E. auch genügen.

Comment: @userunknown Bei Rechenaufgaben mag das nahe beieinander liegen, wir haben aber auch zB Beweisaufgaben. Da sind kreative Schritte nötig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wie wäre es mit:

> Grundlagentest

Der Begriff ist so allgemein, dass er alle Anforderungen erfüllen sollte. Trotzdem ist es natürlich Geschmackssache, ob es dann noch passt und nicht zu schnöde klingt ...

Comment: Trifft in unserem Fall zu, es geht tatsächlich um Grundlagen. Gute Idee, danke!